# convert docx to pdf using pypandoc with BytesIO file path

Tags: python, pdf, docx, pandoc, pypandoc

I want to get docx file from azure blob storage, convert it into pdf and save it again into azure blob storage. I want to use pypandoc to convert docx to pdf.

```
pypandoc.convert_file('abc.docx', format='docx', to='pdf',outputfile='abc.pdf')
```

But, I want to run this code in azure function where I will not get enough space to save files, hence I am downloading file from azure blob storage using BytesIO as a stream as follows.

```
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(cs)
container_client=blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(filename)
streamdownloader=blob_client.download_blob()

stream = BytesIO()
streamdownloader.download_to_stream(stream)
```

now I want to convert my docx file which is accessible using `stram` to pdf. converted pdf also savable as BytesIO stream so could upload it into blob storage without taking system memory. but pypandoc showing error as `RuntimeError: source_file is not a valid path` 
if you could suggest some other way to convert docx to pdf which could handle BytesIO file format, then I like to mention I will work in linux environment where library like doc2pdf does not support.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?